# How to get specific unique string value in Prisma

Tags: sql, node.js, prisma

In my Prisma model, how can I define data type `string` with a specific format like character with an auto-generated number something like this `C00000001`?

Here is my model:

```
model Company {
  id                 String      @unique // Here it should insert C00000001, C00000002, and so on
  companyName        String      @unique
  companyDescription String
  createdAt          DateTime    @default(now())
  updatedAt          DateTime    @updatedAt
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, this feature is not supported in Prisma. There is a feature request to support custom-defined id patterns as seen [here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/6719). Some workarounds that utilize the use of middleware are also discussed there.